# "clan" generated by singletons of a set

Tags: measure-theory

According to this question 
["σ-algebra generated by singletons of X
"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954720/sigma-algebra-generated-by-singletons-of-x)

I unserstand that :
if $X$ is an uncountable set then 
$$\sigma(\{\{x\}:x\in X\})=\{E \subset X: E \text{ or } E^c \text{is at last countable} \}$$

But what is confusing me that, I know that for any arbitrary set  $A\in \mathcal{P}(X) $ we can write it as 
$$A=\underset{a\in A}{\cup}\{a\}$$
so I can conclude that $A\in \sigma(\{\{x\}:x\in X\})$
and hence $\mathcal{P}(X)=\sigma(\{\{x\}:x\in X\})$

I don't see here where the condition of contibulity appear and which fallacy  I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sigma$-algebras are closed only under countable unions, so if $A\in\mathcal P(X)$ is uncountable, writing it as $\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ is not enough to conclude that $A$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra (and in fact it doesn't), since the union isn't countable.