# Are the sets below $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Are the following sets sigma algebra?

1. $X=R$,
   $\{E\subseteq{R}:E ~\text{is compact or}~ \overline{E}=E^c ~\text{is compact}\}$.
2. $X$ is an infinite set, $\{E\in{X} : |E|≤ \aleph_{0} 
    ~\text{or}~ |E^c|≤\aleph_{0}\}$.

- In 2 it means that E is countable ot its complement is countable.
  Trying to show that the two sets are sigma algebra, by proving the 2 conditions, that sigma algebra is closed under complementary and countable unions.I tried to see this by using the properties of unions and intersections of compact sets (countable sets in 2)..but it wasn't so helpful.

Comment: In this forum, you are supposed to give your own efforts and comments.  Do not expect us to do it for you.  For example, in 1.  Can you prove some of the parts in the definition of "$\sigma$-algebra"?  Which parts remain to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Does the following set belong to the given collection?
   $$
   \bigcup_{n\ge 2}[n^{-1}, 1-n^{-1}]
   $$
2. Look, for example, at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954720/sigma-algebra-generated-by-singletons-of-x).

Comment: I know that a closed + bounded interval/segment is compact in R.

Comment: But the union you mentioned is not compact as i guess, so it does not belong to the set above.then i need to look at the complement which id [1,0] ?

Comment: The union is $A\equiv (0,1)$. Neither $A$ nor $A^c$ is compact...

Comment: It seems you are in favor of looting...

Comment: @Almaa No, $A$ is $(0,1)$.