# Let $X=\mathbb{R}$. Find the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singletons $\{ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Tags: measure-theory

There are a few posts on here that answer this question. I have a problem with a specific solution which differs from the solutions given here. I think my issue lies in understanding what $\sigma(\{x\}, x \in \mathbb{R})$ represents. The solution goes as follows:

> Denote by $\Sigma = \sigma(\{x\}, x \in \mathbb{R})$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra defined by $$\mathcal{A} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: A \text{ is countable or } A^c \text{ is countable}\}$$
> It is clear that $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$, and so $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{A}$.

I do not understand this. $\Sigma$ is uncountable (as it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by an uncountable set. That is, the set of singletons in $\mathbb{R}$) and hence $\Sigma^c$ is countable? But why does this follow from $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$? It goes on

> On the other hand, if $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then either $A$ or $A^c$ is countable. Without loss of generality assume that $A$ is countable. Then $A$ is a countable union of singletons, as such $A\in \Sigma$ as well as $A^c \in \Sigma$. This means $\mathcal{A} \subset \Sigma$.

Here the inclusion $\mathcal{A} \in \Sigma$ does not make sense.

I think I am having trouble understanding $\sigma$-algebras. Because $\{ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is an uncountable set, the $\sigma$-algebra generated from it is also uncountable? I do not understand how this can be otherwise.

Is it the case that the $\sigma$-algebra contains finite unions of singletons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sigma$-algebra generated by singletons of $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954720/sigma-algebra-generated-by-singletons-of-x)

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand this. $\Sigma$ is uncountable (as it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by an uncountable set. That is, the set of singletons in $\mathbb{R}$) and hence $\Sigma^c$ is countable?

$\Sigma$ is **not** a subset of $\Bbb R$. It is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$, so, it is a mistake to try to claim $\Sigma\in\mathcal{A}$ by checking whether or not it is (co)countable. The authors said $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, which is a completely different statement to $\Sigma\in\mathcal{A}$ and has very little to do with the cardinality of $\Sigma$. Also, it is not true that the complement of an uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ is countable - consider $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$ are both uncountable - so this argument wouldn't have worked anyway.

$\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is true because $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing each singleton; by definition of $\Sigma=\sigma(\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R)$, $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ holds.

> Here the inclusion $\mathcal{A}\in\Sigma$ does not make sense.

It doesn't, no. Because it should be $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\Sigma$, which *does* make sense (I am not sure if that is a typo or a point of confusion for you).

What an inclusion like $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\Sigma$ means is that every single $A\in\mathcal{A}$ has that $A\in\Sigma$. This is exactly the same as "ordinary" inclusion, this is not a different "type" of inclusion. View $\Sigma$ and $\mathcal{A}$ as bags of subsets of $\Bbb R$; inclusion means that one bag is able to fit inside the other.

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by an uncountable set *is* uncountable, yes. In fact, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by any countable subset of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable (I've seen that said once, I'll try to find a reference).

Comment: I have typed the solution precisely how it is in the solutions manual.

Comment: @HMPtwo In the grey text you have, yes. In your "own-thoughts" commentary, you have made a mistake with $\mathcal{A}\in\Sigma$ (that is not what the text wrote). Do not confuse $A$ with $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: ahhhh yes I see. My bad. I am just digesting your remarks :)

Comment: No worries ${}{}$

Comment: I am still not clear on things. Am I correct in saying that if $x \in \Sigma$ then $x$ is a countable union of singletons?

Comment: I am still struggling with $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{A}$

Comment: @HMPtwo If $x$ is a real number then technically, $\{x\}\in\Sigma$, not $x\in\Sigma$, and this holds by definition of $\Sigma$. $\{x\}\in\mathcal{A}$ will also be true because $\{x\}$ is a countable union of singletons because it is a union of *one* singleton, namely $\{x\}$ itself. Here, "countable" refers to "finite or countably infinite", as is common. But if you used the letter $x$ to refer to a general set then this is not true, $\Sigma$ contains uncountable sets

Comment: $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ holds by definition of the generated $\sigma$-algebra as the **smallest** $\sigma$-algebra containing the generators. $\mathcal{A}$ contains each of the generators $\{x\}$ for $x\in\Bbb R$, and is a $\sigma$-algebra, so because $\Sigma$ is **smallest** we have $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$

Comment: This is what I am struggling with: It is clear that $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$, and so $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{A}$. Why does it follow from $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$? I'm really sorry. This just has not clicked

Comment: I can see that $\{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$ but now why $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{A}$ follows.

Comment: @HMPtwo No need to apologise, we are all confused about something at some point. $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ follows from the comment about **smallest** $\sigma$-algebras, I suggest you re-read that one. If it still doesn't make sense, I don't know what else to say except: review your notes about the 'generated' $\sigma$-algebras. *By definition*, $\Sigma\subset\mathcal{A}$ follows

Comment: Finally, the penny has dropped. Thanks for your patience :)